# Hierarchy issue Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im making a simple game in Unity 3d, basically you have a backdround object with more gameobjects on top, what you have to do is drag those game objects into some trash cans, as soon as you hit the correct trash can with the correct object said object gets deleted, the idea of the game is that when you put all the objects in the corect cans you win the game

I have the drag and acceptance all made but i cant figure out how to make the script so that when theres no more objects, you win the game.

I've been trying to use Hierarchy on an empty game object thats the parent for the objects that you have to destroy, but i dont know how to actually delete the objects so that the code can register it, any help?

The code for the drag and the code im using for the trash cans:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class arrastrar : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler
{
    public float z = 0.0f;
    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePosition.z = z;
        transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);
    }
}
```

> And the code inside the trashcans

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class botarBasura: MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.name == "cubo")
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
    } else if (other.gameObject.name == "escombros")
    {
    other.gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(-1, 2.5f, -2); //If its not the correct trash can it returns the object to the starting position
    }
    } else if ( other.gameObject.name == "botellas")
    {
    other.gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 2.5f, -2);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: All GameObjects have an inherited `.Destroy()` method you can use to destroy them. I would advise disabling them instead, though. In general its better to pool your objects and hide them when inactive, returning them to the pool. You want to avoid instantiating during gameplay as much as you can. A few instantiations/destroys aren't noticeable performance-wise, but when you start handling hundreds or thousands of gameobjects and your garbage collector is pulling overtime performance can get quite rough. Best to get used to the concept of pooling early while its less complex

Comment: Do the draggable objects have some kind of component/script/tag on them that only they have?

Comment: Yes @Ruzihm they do, they have a  Drag script, that, well, as the name says are used to drag the objects, im attaching it bellow

Comment: @DetectivePikachu a pool is overkill unless you have hundreds of objects, it's likely just needless complexity here

Answer (score 3):

You can use a scriptable object to keep track of your object. Objects just need to add and remove themselves to a list in the scriptable object in their OnEnable() and OnDisable() callbacks. When an object removes itself you can have code check to see if there are no more objects left and trigger an event that something in your scene will react to.

(Dragable Object)

```
public class DragableObject : MonoBehaviour{

//reference to the scriptable object
public DragableObjectSet RuntimeSet;

void OnEnable(){
    RuntimeSet.Add(this);
}

void OnDisable(){
    RuntimeSet.Remove(this);

    //you can put code checking if the runtime set is empty here
    //or you can put it in the DragableObjectSet Remove method
}

}
```

Scriptable object example code

```
public DragableObjectSet : ScriptableObject
{
    public List<DragableObject> RuntimeSet = new List<DragableObject>();


    public void Add(DragableObject obj){
        RuntimeSet.Add(obj);
    }

    public void Remove(DragableObject obj){
        RuntimeSet.Remove(obj);
        if(RuntimeSet.Count() == 0)
           //some code here raising an event (if desired)
    }
}
```

This type of object is called a runtime set and is detailed in this talk around the 40 minute mark.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raQ3iHhE_Kk

Comment: Saw the question and immediately went to grab that video =)
Here's the timecode: https://youtu.be/raQ3iHhE_Kk?t=2398

Answer (score 1):

You can get an array of all active & not-yet-destroyed GameObjects with some enabled component with `Object.FindObjectsOfType<ComponentType>();`. Once you have that, you could then look at the length of that array.

So, you could do something like this in the code that destroys/deactivates the draggable gameobject:

```
GameObject otherObject = /* get draggable object to possibly destroy */;

if ( /* test to remove otherObject */ )
{
    // deactivate the draggable object
    otherObject.setActive = false;

    // get all other draggable objects
    DraggableObject[] remainingDraggableObjects = Object.FindObjectsOfType<DraggableObject>();

    if (remainingDraggableObjects.Length == 0)
    {
        // there are no more active gameobjects with enabled DraggableObject component
        // handle win condition here.
    }   
}
```

In your specific example, it could look like this:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.name == "cubo")
    {
        other.gameObject.setActive = false; // better than destroying in most cases

        // get all other draggable objects
        arrastrar[] remainingObjects = Object.FindObjectsOfType<arrastrar>();

        if (remainingObjects.Length == 0)
        {
            // there are no more active gameobjects with enabled arrastrar component
            // handle win condition here.
        }  
    }

    // ...
```

Comment: Im gonna attach the code that i've been using to drag my objects close to the trash cans.
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class arrastrar : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler
{
    public float z = 0.0f;

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePosition.z = z;

        transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);
 
    }
}

Comment: Oh and another thing that i don't know if its ideal, i have the script that deletes the objects in each type of trash can, the script searches for the name of the object on collision and if the name of said object is the correct one it deletes that object, so if i am using this method, where would i put the array and this script itself?

Comment: @PanmoRamirez Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58700805/edit) to include that code.

Comment: @PanmoRamirez As the comments in my answer suggest, it would be wherever you test to remove the other object. I really can't be any more detailed without seeing the code you're using.

Comment: @PanmoRamirez I edited my answer to show how it could look in your code

Comment: Im gonna try it out and ill let you know, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

A solution could possibly be using a singleton:

Create a new empty GameObject and add this code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class TrashCounter : MonoBehaviour {
    public static TrashCounter instance = null;    
    public int counter = 0;

    void Awake(){ instance = this; }
}
```

Now, wherever you create an object (or in the `Start()` method of any object code), you just need to do `TrashCounter.instance.counter++` and you will have your trash count.

After that, you just need to update this counter everytime you delete an object by doing `TrashCounter.instance.counter--` and after you ask `if(TrashCounter.instance.counter == 0) WinGame()`.

Comment: Im gonna look it up then cus i have no idea of what a singleton is, ty for the tip though!